# Setting property values of Generic List<T>

Tags: c#, list

I have the following class which I used to store a list of items to be deleted and its results (can be deleted or not).

```
public class RecItemModel
{
    [JsonPropertyName("recId")]
    public long REC_ID { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("recNo")]
    public string REC_NO { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [JsonPropertyName("recName")]
    public string REC_NAME { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [JsonPropertyName("resultId")]
    public short RESULT_ID { get; set; }
}
```

I do have another class which inherits the above with additional properties

```
public class VehicleRecItemModel : RecItemModel
{
    [JsonPropertyName("vehNo")]
    public string VEH_NO { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [JsonPropertyName("driver")]
    public string DRIVER { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

Now I want to have a generic List extension function which allows me to update `RESULT_ID` based on a condition like this:

```
var List<int> toDelList = new() { 1, 2, 13, 24 };

delList.Where(i => toDelList.Contains((int)i.REC_ID))
       .ForEach(i => i.RESULT_ID = (short)CommonResultId.Ok);
```

Please advise how can I achieve it. Thanks.

Comment: It seems that you only lack the extension method declaration around.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Are you unable to write a loop to modify the list? Are you unable to extract an extension method? Are you struggling to make that method generic? What have you tried so far and what issues did you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way is a classical foreach loop:

```
foreach(var item in delList.Where(x => toDelList.Contains((int)x.REC_ID)))
{
      item.RESULT_ID = (short)CommonResultId.Ok
}
```

If you absolutely want to use the `ForEach` method, you have to call `ToList()` first. This is necessary, because `Where` returns an `IEnumerable<T>`, but `ForEach` ist only defined for `List<T>`.

```
delList.Where(i => toDelList.Contains((int)i.REC_ID)).ToList()
       .ForEach(i => i.RESULT_ID = (short)CommonResultId.Ok);
```

But this will create a new list, which needs time for copying the references. You gain nothing by this approach. In my point of view, readability is worse than in the first approach. Because of that, I don't recommend using it.

If you want a generic method that can deal with a `List<RecItemModel>`or with a `List<VehicleRecItemModel>`, you can use a generic method with a type constraint:

```
public void UpdateList<T>(List<T> delList) where T : RecItemModel
{
  foreach(var item in delList.Where(x => toDelList.Contains((int)x.REC_ID)))
  {
        item.RESULT_ID = (short)CommonResultId.Ok
  }
}
```

Comment: The issue is that delList might be List<RecItemModel> or List<VehicleRecItemModel>. I want to have a generic function that can deal with both classes. Any idea?

Comment: @RyanOng That should not be a problem. I extended my answer to explain that.

Comment: SomeBody please consider also updating the question with information provided by OP as @RyanOng for some reason was not able to do so leaving the question unclear and lacking research effort (which may attract downvotes). Also consider adding why OP needed the generic method where `IEnumerable<RecItemModel>` would work just fine...

Comment: This work for me. I have added this method to a List extension. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ConvertAll:

```
delList.Where(i => toDelList.Contains((int)i.REC_ID))
   .ConvertAll(i => i.RESULT_ID = (short)CommonResultId.Ok);
```